# Function cannot be initialized on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, github-webhook

I am deploying a simple function on Google Cloud Functions but I am getting a `Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason.` error.

This is my code:

index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const crypto = require('crypto');
const {
    Octokit
} = require("@octokit/core");
const moment = require('moment');

const myFunc = (req, res) => {
   // My Code
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "jane doe",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@octokit/core": "^4.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4"
  }
}
```

Other files are:

- .env file to set environment variables
- package-lock.json
- node_modules folder

I am deploying using the UI, and have set the entry point to `myFunc`.
[image: deployment]

My deployment is unsuccessful when doing it this way and this is what my error logs say:

- `Function 'myFunc' is not defined in the provided module.`
- `Did you specify the correct target function to execute?`
- `Could not load the function, shutting down.`
- `Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason.`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't you need to export the function? like `exports.myFunc = myFunc;`?

Comment: @EvgeniDikerman, i just tried that. Still getting an error.

Comment: I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 0):

You may see this kind of  error messages when the process running your code exited either due to a runtime error or a deliberate exit. There is also a small chance that a rare infrastructure error occurred.

There can be multiple reasons behind the error you’re receiving, please refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#function_terminated) which will help you with the solution to all those reasons.

Please refer to this section to see the complete solution [walkthrough](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#:%7E:text=in%20Logging.-,The%20solution,-For%20a%20background) and refer to this [Github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow-cx/issues/243).

As it is less likely to be infrastructure error to confirm on this I suggest you to raise a support ticket with google as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to at least export myFunc, for it to be found? Thats' what the error says. So,

```
export const myFunc...
```

or

```
module.exports = {
  myFunc
}
```

Is that what cloud functions look like these days? I thought you had to use @google-cloud/functions-framework, like in the samples:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-helloworld-get

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.http('helloGET', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```